# Вывод определенных строк в DBGrid

Tags: access, delphi

Здравствуйте! Есть вот какой вопрос.
У меня на одной форме имеется несколько Panel-ов, они у меня используются в качестве кнопки. По событию OnClick у меня в таблице DBGrid на другой форме должны отображаться строки, которые подходят под определенный критерий. Пыталась сделать с помощью приведенного ниже когда, но ничего не получилось. Выборка должна осуществляться по столбцу №Stolika. Соответсвенно, на другую панель я бы хотела повесить условие №Stolika:=2 Помогите пожалуйста.

```
procedure TForm5.Panel1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    form5.hide;
    form6.show;
    Form6.ADOQuery1.Close;
    Form6.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    Form6.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select №Stolika,Bludo, Kolichestvo, Price,DateZakaza from ZakazIzMenu where №Stolika:=1');
    Form6.ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
    Form6.ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Анечка, порекомендую Вам, не использовать такие символы № в названии полей (это относится и к другим спецсимволам). Второе, если Вы хотите чтобы ваше условие срабатывало, когда Stolika равно 1, то надо делать так это:

```
select Stolika,Bludo, Kolichestvo, Price,DateZakaza from ZakazIzMenu where (Stolika=1)
```

Это в самом делфи приравнивание осуществляется через :=, а в SQL коде просто =.

Если Stolika строковое значение, то обрамляем в кавычки:

```
 'select Stolika,Bludo, Kolichestvo, Price,DateZakaza from ZakazIzMenu where (Stolika='+#39+'1'+#39+')'
```

Comment: @IntegralAL, спасибо вам большое! Прям большое прибольшое))) Такая глупая ошибка была оказывается))

Comment: Можно использовать и такие символы, только заключайте имя поля в квадратные скобки.